# Looking for an expression for "inaudible"

Tags: phrase-request, phrasal-verbs

I'm looking for an expression that allows me to say when someone's voice becomes **inaudible** or **silent**, something like a phrasal verb.

Comment: you need to add some more context. You want someone for *that person* or *the action* of going *mute*?

Comment: Imprek, please provide an example sentence in which you might fit such a word or phrase. "The old ladies pottered off in the direction of the few shops in the village, their chattering **dying away** slowly until the songs of birds and the wispering of the leaves were again the only sounds to be heard".

Answer (score 1):

As a person's voice becomes softer and softer it **trails off** until it is imperceptible.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use *fading away* a lot to describe this, for example:

> His voice **faded away** in the distance as we travelled.

or

> As the train sped away from the station, the noise and commotion from the city **faded away** slowly.